# Using return statement does not work compared to direct function call

Tags: javascript, loops, scope, return

I'm a newbie in JavaScript. I'm scratching my head because of these two samples I've just made.

```
function main() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        var x = arr.push(i);
        return x;
    }
}

console.log(main());
```

vs

```
function main() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        var x = arr.push(i);
        console.log(x);
    }
}

main();
```

The second one outputs 1-10 in the console, but the first one outputs only 1. Why is the first one (that uses `return`) not working similarly with the second one (that directly outputs when the function is called)? Is there a solution for the first one?

Comment: Because the `return` of the first one finishes the function execution. Return when used in a loop will stop the loop too. A function can only return once.

Comment: The `return` statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it exits the function at the return statement.

But if you add the return at the end it will give back an array.

```
function main() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(main());
```

In `x` was only saved the length of the array after the `push`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is happening in your code:

```
function main() {
var arr = [];
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    var x = arr.push(i);
    return x;
}
}

console.log(main());
```

Not only in JS but probably in all C-based programming languages, the keyword `return` exists your current function call. So what happens here is you get in the function, `i` becomes 1 then with return you explicitly tell the function to stop and display the current value of `i`.

In the second version, you just console.log() the variable you want written, and that does not interfere with the function in any way, letting it run until the `for` loop is through.

You can find out a bit more about this behavior [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).